# Fixing the size of layouts

Tags: qt, qt4

Is there a way to make the layoutStretch property always be obeyed? E.g. I have it set to "1,3,2", but then a widget (a label) in the first part (the "1" in "1,3,2") expands (when more text is added), and then the 1:3:2 ration is no longer respected. That is, the "1:3:2" ratio turns into something more like "3:1:3".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should take a look at the property [`QWidget::sizePolicy`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop). It controls how the layout respects the `sizeHint()` of its children when it updates the geometries.

So what you need to do is: Make the layout ignore the horizontal sizeHints of the child widgets by setting the horizontal sizePolicy of the three child widgets to `QSizePolicy::Ignored`:

```
QLabel *label = ...;
...
label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, label->sizePolicy().verticalPolicy());
```

(The second argument will ensure that the vertical policy isn't changed by this statement.
Of course, you should set the size policy of every child widget, this example code is only for the label.)

Note that the contents of your layout have to be widgets; I think nested layouts can't be assigned a size policy (but I might be wrong). At least using QtDesigner, there is no way of applying a size policy to a layout itself (if it isn't the layout of a widget). See comments for details.

---

In QtDesigner, you can set the sizePolicy of the child widgets like this:

*Before:*
[image]
*Shrinked:*
[image]
*Select the items in the layout:*
[image]
*Set the horizontal size policy to "Ignored":*
[image]
*Result:*
[image]

Comment: in QtDesigner I clicked on one of the 3 verticalLayout widgets that are the three objects in the horizontalLayout widget (the one that has the 1:3:2 layoutStretch). However, there is no sizePolicy, only layoutLeftMargin, layoutTopMargin, layoutRightMargin, layoutBottomMargin, layoutSpacing, layoutStretch, and layoutSizeConstraint.

Comment: @DavidDoria I added screenshots for QtDesigner.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was still not clear. I have verticalLayout widgets that are the children of a horizontalLayout widget. These verticalLayout widgets are the ones that I want to fix the ratio of, but they do not have a "sizePolicy" property.

Comment: Ah okay, so then you should put the contents of the vertical layout (which *isn't* a widget!) into a real widget, set the layout to be vertically. Then put this widget (now it *is* a widget!) into the horizontal layout / outer widget. Finally, set the horizontal size policy of the recently created widget (where you applied the vertical layout) to "Ignored". The problem is that you can't set size policy of a layout item (if it isn't a widget; in QtCreator you see a red border), but you can set it of a widget having a layout. I hope you understand what I mean; it can be confusing, I know ;)

Comment: Ah, ok. In almost every program I have layouts nested like this - should I always make them widgets with a specified layout instead of raw "layouts"?

Comment: No, in most cases it's even better not to use widgets (it's more "lightweight"). But in some cases you want additional functionality; setting the size policy is such an case; applying different style properties might be another example. But as said, in most cases nested layout *items* are ok and just simpler than nested *widgets*.